# Instability with dual socket Xeon and Windows 7 Ultimate

Tags: windows-7, xeon

**Computer Specs**

PSU: 1U SR1600 server chassis PSU

MOTHERBOARD: Intel 5520UR dual socket server board.

GPU: Matrox g200e

CPU: Dual quad core Xeon 5570 Nehalem EP

RAM: 2 x 2gb DDR3 sticks

**Description of problem**

I bought an Intel SR1600 server with an Intel 5520UR dual socket server board and dual quad core 5570 Xeon Nehalem EP processors to use with Adobe Premiere by my GF.
Initially I installed Windows 10 and the computer worked fine, I had to install the graphics driver for the Matrox g200e via INF modification and also allowing 1920x1080p resolution by modifying some registers.
It worked well enough but I had issues with tearing in videos.
In an attempt to solve the tearing issues I decided to install Windows 7 Ultimate, which proved to be immediately unstable during the last configuration part of the installation and immediately after installation.

Any application you would want to use would crash and some wouldn't even start e.g. Task Manager.

**What I've tried so far to resolve the issue**

I did some research and read that some users were having problems with dual Xeons and having C-State power saving features enabled, so I went to the bios and disabled those.

After that the system became much more usable and harder to crash but I still couldn't succesfully run the task manager. At this point I used msconfig to set the number of processors to two explicitely, but the same problems persisted.
Here I decided to install a newer version of the Windows 7 install disc that had more updates built in, because I thought that the problem could have been solved in a further update I wasn't being able to grab (because of general system unstability and not being able to install WLAN drivers for the wifi adapter)
So I re-installed from newer version of the Windows 7 install disc that included security and important updates up to May 2017, but the same problems still persisted.

I did a windows memory test at this point, to see if the problem was a bad ram stick. The test indicated no ram issues.

At this point I was thinking that the problem might have to do with the bios, so I grabbed the lastest firmware for the board from Intel and installed it from the EFI shell.

Luckily, the bios update was succesful (I didn't have access to a UPS because this was on my GFs house and I wanted to get it done ASAP).
Logged into windows and the system was still unstable, but this time around I could actually open the Task Manager to take a look at processor stats.
I quickly realized that the processor was alternating from 0% to 1% to 90% to a 100% load on IDLE.

My bios settings at this point were C3 states disabled, C6 states disabled, and Intel Speed Step disabled.

I tried to google for a hotfix for Nehalem EP Xeons but didn't find one some I'm posting my problem here to see if someone has any ideas about how to solve the problem or continue investigating.

PD: I installed the motherboard chipset drivers right after both installations.

Comment: Servers are not designed to run with consumer OS's.  I suspect possibly multiple hardware incompatibilities or missing supporting drivers/firmware.  One between the server itself an windows, two between the graphics the hardware and windows.    Maybe try a server grade OS and try and reproduce the problems to eliminate hardware incompatibilities with Windows?  Also, possibly try different graphics options (different card) to see if you get a difference in the "tearing"